# Setting an ASP LinkButton control's text via JQuery and JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I have an ASP.net 4.0 site to modify.  In particular, I want to set the text value of a LinkButton control to a filename:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonFile1" runat="server" OnClick="GetFile">
```

I want to do this on the client side with JQuery and a JSON object:

```
 var FileNames = { "name": "testing" };
 var id = ('id=$LinkButtonFile1').val();
 ('id=$LinkButtonFile1').val() = FileNames.name
```

I use 'id=..' because I'm using a Master Page and i found from googling that issue is solved by doing this. Running this is debug on VS2010 reveals that 'val()' is not a valid property.  I've tried many variations including:

```
 var FileNames = { "name": "testing" };
//var id = document.getElementById("<%= $LinkButtonFile1 %>");
//var id = document.getElementById('[id$=LinkButtonFile1]');
var id = document.getElementById('id$=LinkButtonFile1');

var id = document.getElementById('$LinkButtonFile1');
//('[id=$LinkButtonFile1]').val(FileNames.name);
```

which returns id = null.

I've googled many sites trying to get the right syntax but nothing is working for me.  Can anyone tell me the right syntax?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have wrong syntax for setting value.

Change

```
('id=$LinkButtonFile1').val() = FileNames.name
```

To

```
('[id*=LinkButtonFile1]').text(FileNames.name);
```

or using id instead of wild card, preferred approach here

```
('#<%= LinkButtonFile1.ClientID %>').text(FileNames.name);
```

Comment: I tried that which gives the error: Object doesn't support property or method 'val'

Comment: We have to use text instead of val, updated my answer, you can check it over here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/tk5uv/1/

Comment: No, same error with 'text' "Object doesn't support property or method 'text'".  i tried upper case with the same error "Object doesn't support property or method 'Text'".  Thanks for trying Adil!

Comment: Tell me if you can use jQuery and it is successfully added in your page? Make sure your linkbutton exists in the page, if yes check the page source and give me html. I have updated my answer with javascript check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I know this issue is old, but I was looking for the same answer and couldn't find any help.  After a lot of digging, question asking, etc.  I found a solution, and I think that it will help here.

First, lets look at your LinkButton:

> `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonFile1" runat="server" OnClick="GetFile">`

Put ClientIDMode="Static" in there somewhere.  Otherwise when ran you will get something like "MainContent_" prepended to your ID.  Look at your source code of the webpage to verify.

Second, how you are getting a hold of your button...

> `var id = document.getElementById('id$=LinkButtonFile1');`

The getElementById is more javascript-y mixed with jquery.  Lets just stick with one.. jquery.

> `$("#LinkButtonFile1").text(FileNames.name);`

That should allow you to change the text of the linkbutton.  If that doesn't work, possibly try putting the FileNames.name in quotes, or pulling the actual text out directly.